# Как добавить в проект Xamarin (например Xamarin Application) проект, созданный не по шаблону Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, library

Мне нужно добавить в десктопное приложение и в андроид-приложение (на Xamarin) одну общую библиотеку, там нет ни форм, ни Activity – только вычислительная логика. С десктопным приложением проблем нет. Добавление в андроид-приложение невозможно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл Xamarin-проекта:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
        <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
        <ProjectGuid>{MY-PROJECT-GUID}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectTypeGuids>{MY-PROJECT-TYPE-GUID-1};{MY-PROJECT-TYPE-GUID-2}</ProjectTypeGuids>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
        <RootNamespace>MyRootNamespace</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>MyAssemblyName</AssemblyName>
        <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
        <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
        <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.Designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
        <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
        <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
        <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>false</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v11.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
        <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
        <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
        <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
        <LangVersion>9</LangVersion>
        <MandroidI18n>other</MandroidI18n>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
        <Optimize>False</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
        <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
        <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <Optimize>True</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
        <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
        <AndroidLinkMode>SdkOnly</AndroidLinkMode>
        <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="MainActivity.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.Designer.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
        <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\activity_main.axml">
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </AndroidResource>
        <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\colors.xml" />
        <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\ic_launcher_background.xml" />
        <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\strings.xml" />
        <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\styles.xml" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="28.0.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="my-project-path">
        <Project>{my-project-uuid}</Project>
        <Name>SpaceDunyalCore</Name>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Файл проекта, который я хочу добавить:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Я пробовал в оба проекта добавлять теги `TargetFramework`, `TargetFrameworkVersion` - не помогло.

Можно предположить, что платформы Xamarin и .NET содержат разные библиотеки (включая самые базовые, System). Но при этом странно, что когда я попробовал добавить пакет NuGet в андроид-проект, который я ранее добавлял в .NET-проекты (HTMLAgilityPack), то пакет совершенно спокойно добавился в Xamarin-проект. Я пытаюсь понять, как мне тоже создать такой универсальный проект.

P.S. Сейчас я создал XamarinLibrary:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и мне приходится постоянно дублировать код в случае изменений, но, сами понимаете, это неудобно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что Xamarin и .NET Core действительно несовместимы. Для того, чтобы создать связанные проекты, нужно выбирать проект Android не в рубрике Xamarin, а в .NET Core:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]